# Globally blocking all outgoing network requests from a node.js app

Tags: node.js, networking

Is there a way to guarantee that all potential outgoing network requests from an app are blocked?

You may be confused why one would want something like that when you can just "not make a network request" instead of trying to find a way to globally block any network request.

But I'm looking for a guaranteed approach that will completely block any potential outgoing network requests, that will work globally across the app, so that even if some undetected dependency gets merged into the code in the future, it will just block those requests.

Comment: Not really.. at least, not directly with just node; that's one of the reason we got [Deno](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/permissions) instead

Comment: @Federkun not even a hackish way of doing this? I thought this is a big enough pain point that people would have figured out some adhoc ways of dealing with this even before Deno came along...

Comment: oh yeah, nothing stop you from trying to block those requests at the firewall level, or using a proxy with a whitelist, etc

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this inside the app (using node.js) instead of running a separate program. I guess one way is if there is a way to implement a proxy that intercepts all networking requests (not just HTTP). Basically this is the gist of my question. Is there a self contained way to do this just with node.js

Comment: I mean, you could _tecnically_ monkey patching the `net` module, but that doesn't give you any guarantees

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to guarantee that all potential outgoing network requests from an app are blocked?

Not from within nodejs.  There are a lot of potential APIs within nodejs that a developer can use to cause networking to happen from within nodejs and there is no foolproof mechanism within nodejs for blocking access to all of them.

In fact, someone coding in your app can even use child_process to run additional nodejs applications or other applications on the computer that can all do networking.

> But I'm looking for a guaranteed approach that will completely block any potential outgoing network requests, that will work globally across the app, so that even if some undetected dependency gets merged into the code in the future, it will just block those requests.

Your best option here is to use either a proxy or firewall that controls outbound networking from your host.